# PHP - Update public variable

Tags: php, class, variables

Here's what I'm doing:

```
<?php
$csvObj = new Csv2Parser($file);
$csvObj->loopContents();
$csvObj->looplimitrows = 9; // why does this get ignored?
?>
```

This **looplimitrows** is always returning **5** rows, instead of the **9** I am wanting.
Am I not doing it right?

Here's the Class:

```
class Csv2Parser
{
    private $filepath; 

    public $looplimitrows = 5; 

    /*
      .... __construct() goes here...
    */

    public function loopContents(){
      $looplimitrows = $this->looplimitrows;
      $linecount=0;
      $fp = fopen($targetFile, "r"); // open the file
      while ($line = fgetcsv($fp)) {
      $linecount++;

        if(!empty($looplimitrows) && $linecount > $looplimitrows){ break; }

        echo $line[0]; // first column only

      }//eof while()

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It get's ignored as it's not set before you loop through the csv therefor the limit is 5 as that's it's default value.

```
public $looplimitrows = 5;
```

You need to set `Csv2Parser::looplimirows` as below.

```
$csvObj = new Csv2Parser($file);
$csvObj->looplimitrows = 9; // It needs to go here.
$csvObj->loopContents();
```

Alternatively, try this :)

```
<?php
ini_set('auto_detect_line_endings', true);

class Csv2Parser {

    private $rowLimit = NULL;

    private $fileHandle = NULL;
    private $data = NULL;

    public function __construct($filename) 
    {

        if (!file_exists($filename))
            throw new Exception("Can't find file:" . $filename);

        $this->fileHandle = fopen($filename, "r");
    }


    public function get($n) 
    {
        $this->rowLimit = (int) $n;

        return $this;
    }


    public function rows()
    {
        $linecount = 0;

        while (($line = fgetcsv($this->fileHandle, 1000, ",")) !== false) {
            $linecount++;

            if(!is_null($this->rowLimit) && $linecount > $this->rowLimit)
                break;


            $this->data[] = $line;

        }

        return $this->data;
    }
}


$csv = new Csv2Parser("my.csv");
print_r($csv->get(9)->rows()); // Could not be more self explanitory
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the `loopContents()` method without first setting the public variable `looplimitrows`. So the method executes with the default value of `looplimitrows`. First set the `looplimitrows` public variable and call the `loopContents()` method.